# Can I handoff from iOS App to Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I know that you can handoff from the Watch to the iOS App, but I have a use-case where I want to do this the other way round.

The user would create a set of rules on the phone using a more involved UI than would be possible on the watch, then handoff to the watch (deliberately, with something like a "send to watch" button) in order to monitor the results of their settings periodically on the Watch over the next 30 minutes or so.

Is this possible, and if so how do you do it?

Comment: Your best option is to fake the "hand off to watch" aspect of it, save the state info you want to access on the watch, then read that info when the user launches your watch app.

Comment: Do you need to launch the watch app or just notify an already running watch app that the user did something in the iPhone app?

Comment: Idea was to notify and launch the watch app. Sharing data is working fine when the app is running. iOS decides where Notifications go, so I can't use that to force it to go to the watch. Looks like the user will manually have to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Directly using Handoff is not possible from iPhone to Apple Watch, because watchOS doesn't have any UI or code to show handoff apps from iPhone.

To have a similar effect, you could do one of the followings:

1- You could simply tell the user to open Watch app. If the user opens it, it could connect to iOS app to receive Handoff data.

2- You can save data to Apple Watch by `WatchConnectivity` or in iCloud. Then, anytime the user opens the Watch app, it can receive data from iCloud or `WatchConnectivity`, no matter it is a minute later or a week.

> **Note**
>
> You need to check whether the app is installed, or if there is a paired Apple Watch first:

**Swift**

```
import WatchConnectivity

if WCSession.isSupported(){
    if WCSession.defaultSession().watchAppInstalled{
        //...
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>

if ([WCSession isSupported]){
    if ([WCSession defaultSession].watchAppInstalled){
        //...
    }
}
```